# Supersymmetric chiral QCD resource recommendations?

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, quantum-chromodynamics

I want somebody to recommend me where I can read about supersymmetric chiral QCD.

Comment: for anybody that might benefit from this comment, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9403202 this is the only thing I have managed to find